# missing_scope in Slack API via fastlane for android CD

Tags: java, android, kotlin, slack, fastlane

i'm trying to implement CD in android dev using fastlane to upload my apk on some slack channel , i used to make a notif system and it runs well but when i try to make a apk distributor it gives me this error :

```
  {"ok":false,"error":"missing_scope","needed":"files:write","provided":"incoming-webhook"}
```

looks like the api need sth else , i give the scope permission as below but it doesn't work :

[image]

and here is the ruby script inside FastFile i use for generating APK and upload it on slack channel

```
lane :slack_build do
      gradle(task: "assembleRelease")
      slack(message: "Build Successful!")
      upload_to_slack()
end

# Add this to your Fastfile
desc "Upload the APK to Slack channel"
private_lane :upload_to_slack do |options|
      file_path = lane_context[SharedValues::GRADLE_APK_OUTPUT_PATH]
      file_name = file_path.gsub(/\/.*\//,"")
      access_token = "xoxb-961296623494-963876433841-c1PkVmqWSBbDUkbmnbvku4vK"
      channel_name = "test_android_sample"
      sh "echo Uploading " + file_name + " to Slack"
      sh "curl https://slack.com/api/files.upload -F token=\"" + access_token + "\" -F channels=\"" + channel_name + "\" -F title=\"" + file_name + "\" -F filename=\"" + file_name + "\" -F file=@" + file_path
    end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

seems i just need to reinstall app from the yellow warning on top of the api-slack web site , simple and easy :(